# How can I draw a boxplot of an R table?

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a table produced by calling table(...) on a column of data, and I get a table that looks like:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19 
346 351 341 333 345 415 421 425 429 437 436 469 379 424 387 419 392 396 381 421
```

I'd like to draw a boxplot of these frequencies, but calling boxplot on the table results in an error:

```
Error in Axis.table(x = c(333, 368.5, 409.5, 427, 469), side = 2) : 
   only for 1-D table
```

I've tried coercing the table to an array with `as.array` but it seems to make no difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `as.vector` instead of `as.array`. (Arrays typically refer to multidimensional arrays in R, unlike in other languages.)

Comment: do you mean a boxplot (box-and-whisker plot) with a single box, i.e. what you would get from `boxplot(c(346,351,341,...))` ?

Comment: @joran that was it - note me an answer to accept :)

Comment: @BenBolker's got you covered!

Comment: Cheers folks, very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `boxplot(c(tab))` or `boxplot(as.vector(tab))` should work (credit to @joran as well).

Comment: Yep, they both do the job, it was as you described in your comment.